# How to display Border on a Button in UWP when selected

Tags: button, uwp

I need to find how to apply the border on a UWP button when selected. My code is given below. There border set as 1 in visual state and applies it as style to the button. Though the button is clicked button border is not visible there. Please give me an idea of how to do it.

```
//add visual states when button focused
<VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused">

<VisualState.Setters>
<Setter Target="FocusContentPresenter.Border" Value="1" />
<Setter Target="FocusContentPresenter.(UIElement.Opacity) Value="1</VisualState.Setters>

</VisualState.Setters>

....................                  

<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" CornerRadius="10" Background="Blue"   Width="60"  Height="50" Click="OnPenColorChanged"  Margin="3,0,3,0"/>

.................
```

Comment: Edited to be readable

Answer (score 0):

In UWP, changing the state of a control in different states requires the `ControlTemplate`.

This is the default `Button` style:

```xml
<Style x:Key="DefaultButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AccentButtonForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource AccentButtonBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="BackgroundSizing" Value="OuterBorderEdge" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AccentButtonBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
      BackgroundSizing="{TemplateBinding BackgroundSizing}"
      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
      ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
      CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
      HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
      VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
      AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw">

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AccentButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AccentButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AccentButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AccentButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AccentButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AccentButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AccentButtonBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AccentButtonBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AccentButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>

                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </ContentPresenter>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

There are multiple `VisualState`s in it, like `PointerOver`:

```xml
<VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AccentButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AccentButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AccentButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

If you want to change the Button's `BorderBrush` property on `PointerOver` state, you can change the `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` which `Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush"`.

After modification, reference this style on the corresponding button:

```xml
<Button Style="{StaticResource DefaultButtonStyle}" />
```

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you Richard for the comment. But I need to apply border to the button not a border brush in PointerFocused state. I was able to capture PointerFocused event. But unable to apply a border around the button. Is there anyway to do it?  My code is like below. <Setter Target="FocusContentPresenter.Border" Value="1" />
                             <Setter Target="FocusContentPresenter.(UIElement.Opacity) Value="1" />

Comment: <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused">
                                        
                         <VisualState.Setters>
                             <Setter Target="FocusContentPresenter.Border" Value="1" />
                             <Setter Target="FocusContentPresenter.(UIElement.Opacity) Value="1" />
         </VisualState.Setters>

                        </VisualState>

Comment: Hi @IndeewarieBandara `VisualState` of `Button` is preset and the `PointerFocused` you add will not be recognized. You can try to set the style of `Button` with C# code in `Button.GotFocus` event. For `Button` controls, there is no `Border` property. If you want to change the border width, please use `BorderThickness`.